# Remove fb_source from incoming URLs

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

This is my first question here since I usually find what I need to know pretty quickly.
I'm not familiar with editing .htaccess, so I'm rightly nervous about doing so.

Here's what I want to find out.
Can I remove anything after and including the '?' from an incoming URL?

Effectivly turning:
http://example.com/userful-info?fb_junk%20%13%69 
**INTO** http://example.com/userful-info

In another post someone had answered a  question for removing the appended info for fb_action_ids with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)fb_action_ids=
RewriteRule ^/?detail/link- %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]
```

This looks to be in the realm, but I'd like to remove any appended info from my incoming URLs. This is annoying since if something is shared with the appended info it comes from other sites that aren't FB. Like disqus, twitter, tumblr.

I don't want twitter users sharing a url from my site with FB's info. That doesn't make sense.

Thank you,
Alex Theberge

Answer (score 0):

***Though it will break your ability to use query parameters throughout your site (and since/if you are using WordPress, this may present issues for some WordPress functionality, so "buyer beware")***, the following site presents a solution which may solve your issue - http://briancray.com/posts/htaccess-hack-remove-url-query-strings/

What it suggests is that in your `.htaccess` file before the "# BEGIN Wordpress" section, include the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !="" #if there is a query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^p=.* #wordpress users: allow post tempalinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin.* #wordpress users: don't break admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L] #remove query string
```

Comment: Awesome! If I were to use:
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^s=.*`
would that allow for search queries on my site as well?